# How to replace zeros in a kdb+ list in 5 characters of code?

Tags: kdb

I have a list as follows:

```
q) v:1 6 0 7 -2 0f
```

I could replace the 0's in this list with 1 by using the vector conditional:

```
q) ?[v=0;1;v]
```

However, is there any way to perform the same operation with just 5 characters? I.e.

```
q)?[v=0;1;v]~xxxxx
1b
```

EDIT: I got this question as a brain teaser. I'm guessing this stemmed from the idea that q is all about getting your desired result in the least amount of code possible. So this doesn't serve any particular purpose, just for fun

Comment: Hello, what is the use case for needing the solution in 5 characters?

Comment: I got this question as a brain teaser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using the following syntax:

```
v+0=v
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a riddle?? In some very specific (contrived) examples, these could also work assuming non-floats:

```
q)v:1 1 0 7 -2 0 8
q)v^v v
1 1 1 7 -2 1 8
q)v|v v
1 1 1 7 -2 1 8
```

But again, very fabricated examples and not at all usable in the general case as per Avons solution.

BONUS EDIT: k can do the general case in 4 chars

```
q)v:1 6 0 7 -2 0f
q)\
  v+~v
1 6 1 7 -2 1f
```